# Nested fragments: бесконечный прогресс бар

Tags: android

У меня есть `fragment` в котором лежит `viewpager` в него загружаются фрагменты A и B.
Мне нужно разделить каждый из этих фрагментов (A и B) на несколько фрагментов.

На данный момент в xml файлах фрагментов лежит `FrameLayout`.

Код загрузки фрагментов:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.frame1, new Fragment1)).add(R.id.frame2, new Fragment2).commit();
```

В итоге я получаю бесконечный прогресс бар.

Comment: и что? молодец?

Comment: ну мне нужно что бы фрагмент загрузился, а не прогресс бар крутился

Comment: а через хмл пробовал прицепить их?